# If the side that I played loses, will I still get the reward?

Tags: warframe

Playing an operation mission I sided with the Grineer, but seems after all Corpus are about to win.

Grineer are the invaders, the status is 1.7%

If at the end Grineer loses, will I still get the battle pay prize?

Comment: Since the answer is by personal experience, I took care of seeing the results before ticking the answer despite the risk of losing the forma, but it's actually true: you get it even if your faction that you fought for loses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You will still get the reward despite being on the losing side. I can not currently find a strict source for this other than personal experience. [Here](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Invasion) is a link to the wiki in case it has the answer and i just missed it while skimming.